# Index Match and SUM with multiple criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I am trying to get the sum of rows based on a index match lookup from the below table
[Monthly table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFMP3.png)

I am looking at changing the the sum range in the row based on the date I select. for example If I select Oct 16 in a cell drop down, I would get the total of 10 months in 2016 for the given 6 digit code.[Consol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WhywN.png)

I am trying the formula below which gives me the sum of first 10 cells in the row irrespective of the date i select.

=IFERROR(SUM(INDEX(INDIRECT(""&$C$3&"!C:C"),MATCH($A10,INDIRECT(""&$C$3&"!B:B"),0)):INDEX(INDIRECT(""&$C$3&"!C:Z"),MATCH($A10,INDIRECT(""&$C$3&"!B:B"),0),MONTH($C$2))),"")

Appreciate your suggestions pls

Comment: Your screenshots are too blurry to read.

Comment: My apologies. hope the new screenshots are readable

Comment: That helps. Now where is the "cell drop down", and it would help to know the columns for the first screen shot - e.g. what cell is 403300 in? Also, is "Mammoth" the name of the sheet with the lookup table, and is that name in cell C3? If that's correct, then Oct-17 is in C2? And C2 is the drop down?

Comment: "Monthly table" is the data in the sheet named Mammoth. I am using Indirect function to make it dynamic.

Comment: 403300 is in A10 in Consol sheet and in B10 in monthly table. monthly data from Sheet mammoth is pulling alright. The question is to add the only such rows for each code in A:A dependant on the date selected in the drop down C2. You are correct the sheet name is in C3 which is also a drop down.

Comment: I am trying to modify the formula used in C10 =IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT("'"&C$3&"'!A:QZ"),MATCH($A10,INDIRECT("'"&C$3&"'!B:B"),0),MATCH('Consolidated P&L'!C$2,INDIRECT("'"&C$3&"'!7:7"),0)),"") to calculate the year to date(YTD) column. but unable to figureout a way to change the sum range based on the date selection.

Comment: In Console Sheet Cell I10 has the same Formula produces correct result and C10 has value also,,,!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to sum a portion of one row of an array, where the date is less than or equal to a specified value.

First, let's figure out how to get one row of the array.  The INDEX() function

`INDEX(array, row_num, [col_num])`

will return a whole row if the col_num is set to zero.  So this function

`=INDEX(C9:O17,MATCH(403300,B9:B17,0),0))`

returns the row of your data where the Account(?) is 403300.  You can check this by highlighting the formula in the formula bar and typing F9.  That will show the *value* of the formula - an array of the data in the 403300 row.

Now you just need to add up the portion of that row where the month is less than or equal to the specified month.  `SUMIF()` will do this.

`SUMIF(range,criteria,[sum-range])`

SUMIF() checks a specified range (your dates) matching a criteria (<= your specified month) and sums the corresponding cells in the sum_range (the row chosen with the INDEX() formula above).  Putting this all together, and using the mocked-up data table below, this formula

`=SUMIF(C7:O7,"<="&$E$4,INDEX(C9:O17,MATCH($D$4,B9:B17,0),0))`

in G4 gives the sum of the account in D4 through the date in E4.

[image]

I've put everything on one worksheet and without dropdowns, but you can easily add these features.  If you really need to specify the worksheet with a dropdown, you do have to use a lot of INDIRECT()'s, which gets a bit messy.  I came up with this, where the sheet name is in C4:

`=SUMIF(INDIRECT(C4&"!"&"C7:O7"),"<="&E4,INDEX(INDIRECT(C4&"!"&"C9:O17"),MATCH(D4,INDIRECT(C4&"!"&"B9:B17"),0),0))`

I hope this helps, and good luck.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That worked perfect. Greatly appreciate your patience in putting this explanation together.

Comment: Glad to help. If you found this answer useful, please click the check mark at the top left to accept it and remove it from the unanswered queue. Thx.